# Preview of posts contains html characters

Tags: python, django

I have a problem very similar to this guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105169/how-to-clip-html-fragments-without-breaking-up-tags), except that I want to use python (I developed my site on django) to show the preview of my posts (about 100 characters). If you have found a way to do it can you please share it with me?

EDIT: (What I have done so far?) I tried extracting the first 100 characters from the raw post. Something like post[:100]. Its not the correct solution as simple substring of the raw post will obviously contain the html syntaxes that are not properly closed.

EDIT2: I am a django newbie. Actually this is my first project on django.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Something like a popup preview of a different page? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you thought about using an ajax post to a django view, then on success injecting the returned html into the page's dom? Are you trying to display html or a rendered html page? In django you could have a template specifically for an injected page, then it wouldnt contain any html that you wouldnt want it to. Then injecting it would be easy.

Comment: @agconti I dont understand what you meant by "Are you trying to display html or a rendered html page? ". I am trying to render html page containing snapshot of posts. So if my controller returns post[:100] to the view (say index.html written in django template language) how does the view know that whether the end of this substring contains improper html? Also, I dont want to manipulate "post" string (which contains the html) in the controller to keep the design clean.

Comment: got ya. I think I know what you want. If you make a 'preview' post template and render it dynamically into your page through an ajax post it should be straight forward. Doing it this way you don't have to parse a different page and try to display it and it ultimately gives you better control of your previews.

Comment: If you know any, can you point me to some online examples? Thanks @agconti

Comment: Why it is offtopic? Any idea guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any online examples showing just that, but I do have a personal project that includes that functionality; [agconti:stamped](https://github.com/agconti/stamped).

The entire repo is linked above if you want to clone it and test it out, but the code pertinent to your needs would be;

Ajax post:

```
var send_data = { 'name': place.name, 'address': address};

var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken'); 

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
// these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
} 

$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
        }
    }
});


$.ajax({ url: '/results/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: send_data,
    success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
      $("#results").html(response);
      //console.log('success function resp');
      //console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    error: function(obj, status, err) { alert(err); console.log(err); }
  });
```

An example of controlling for injecting a template and normal page viewing:

```
{% extends x|yesno:"stamped/blank.html,stamped/home.html" %}
{% load stamped_custom_tags %}
{% block results %}

<!-- Your HTML Here -->

<h1> title and stuff </h1>

<div> I contain things! </div>

{% endblock %}
```

`home.html` is my `index.html` that contains the `#results` div!

`Blank.html`:

```
{% block results %}{% endblock %}

<!-- to allow for corrected shared rendering 
        with ajax posts and normal django rendering -->
```

Any normal django view that renders a page will return html that that ajax post above will inject into the `#results` div ( not included in the examples above ) on the page the ajax post initiated from.

Edit from your comment:

I'm assuming that what you really want to display in the preview is something important, like a title to an article. I would have a separate view for previews that renders a previews template. In that template I might do something like:

```
<!-- blank because this will be injected into your page -->

{{ article_title|truncatechars:9 }}
```

You could then inject this into your page and display it on mouse over for example.

Comment: Lets say the response you get is <p><b>Hi!</b> How are you?</p> and you want to show only 3 chars in preview i.e.Hi! (in bold).So I guess you are substringing the response in #results div?

Comment: @ShankhoneerChakrovarty updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks @agconti Thats exactly what I was looking for :) but there is one more problem if I use {{ article_title|truncatechars:3 }} in the example above: it will return "<p>"(w/o quotes) instead of Hi! (in bold).

Comment: Since your only truncating the title variable ( this must be generated from the django view and passed to the template as context ) it wont truncate any html. You could truncate the response in the ajax post, but you would run into an issue with cutting html tags.

Comment: Yes exactly, do you have any idea how can i pass the context? Should I parse the "post" string and extract the normal text (by removing the html syntaxes), which I then pass to the ajax function?

Comment: You would pass the context in your django view with the render function. Clone the repo and play around with the truncate tag yourself to get a feel for diffrent ways to do it. Its a working example, so you should be a good context for you to play around in.